# Gremlin, get two vertices that both have an edge to each other

Tags: graph, gremlin, amazon-neptune

So imagine you have 2000 people, they can choose to like someone which creates an edge between them, for example A likes B, now this doesn't necessarily mean that B likes A. How would I write a gremlin query to figure out everyone who likes each other? So where A likes B AND B likes A?

I've been looking around the internet and I've found `.both('likes')` however from what I understand is that this will get everyone who likes someone or who has someone who likes them, not both at the same time.

I've also found this

```
g.V().hasId('1234567').as('y').
  out('likes').
  where(__.in('likes').as('y'))
```

This works for 1 person, however I can't figure out how to get this to work for multiple people.

To me this seems like a simple enough problem for graph however I can't seem to find any solution online. From everything I've been reading it seems to infer that the data should be structured such that, if A likes B, that also means that B likes A. Which is achievable, when you create the edge that A likes B you can check if B already likes A, and if that's the case insert a special edge which is like... A inRelationshipWith B

The query for this would be `g.V().both('inRelationshipWith')` which would make things easier.

Is this an issue with how the data is structured and I am potentially using a graph database incorrectly, or is there actually a simple way to achieve what I want that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. Remember from the other vertex the relationship back to the starting vertex is also an `out` relationship from that vertex's point of view. The following query uses the air-routes data set to find all airports that have a route in both directions (analogous to your mutual friendship case)

```
g.V().
   hasLabel('airport').as('a').
   out().as('b').
   where(out().as('a')).
   select('a','b').
     by('code')
```

This will return pairs of relationships. It will include each airport (friend) twice for example:

```
[a:DFW,b:AUS]
[a:AUS,b:DFW]
```

If you only want one of each pair adding a `dedup` step will reduce the result set to just one pair per relationships.

```
 g.V().
   hasLabel('airport').as('a').
   out().as('b').
   where(out().as('a')).
   select('a','b').
     by('code').
   order(local).
     by(values).
   dedup().
     by(values)
```

Finding the inverse case (where there is not a mutual relationship) is just a case of adding a `not` step to the query.

```
g.V().
  hasLabel('airport').as('a').
   out().as('b').
   where(__.not(out().as('a'))).
   select('a','b').
     by('code')
```

Comment: I have your book open on another tab, I feel like I should read more carefully  http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html - for other people

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be:

```
g.V().as('y').
  out('likes').where(__.out('likes').as('y')).
  path().dedup().
    by(unfold().
      order().by(id).
      dedup().fold())
```

You can try it out here on a sample graph:
https://gremlify.com/radpwsh80o